# Display in Firefox than IE in webapplication

Tags: visual-studio-2010, internet-explorer, firefox, browser

How should I change the settings in VS 2010 so I can display the result (by pressing F5) of my Asp.net MVC application in Firefox instead of IE?

Comment: Try “Default Browser Switcher” (download from Visual Studio Gallery or from Extension Manager inside VS) http://blog.wovs.com/2010/08/make-it-easy-to-change-default-browser.html

Comment: If possible I would like to have IE as default explorer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use Firefox just for one particular project, you can update project properties and set external program to run.

Basically using this technique you can set any browser for any particular project, if you don't want or can't change system default browser.

[image]